# Ruby switch words for hyperlinks without changing the chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two different models: post (it has a content) and keywords (it has the *word* and the *link*). I am trying to make a function which would switch words in post content with the same keywords and its link (so it would work as hyperlink) For examples there is a keyword 'Hello' with some link on it and word 'hello', I want 'hello' in post.content to become a hyperlink with link from 'Hello' in keywords.
Here is my function:

```
   def execute
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    all_keys = Keyword.all.pluck(:key, :link)
    all_keys = all_keys.map.to_h
    all_keys = all_keys.transform_keys(&:downcase)
    new_content = @post.content.to_s
    new_content_downcase = new_content.downcase
    all_keys.map { |key, link| new_content_downcase.gsub!(key, "<a href='#{link}'>#{key}</a>") }
    @post.content = new_content_downcase
    @post.save!
  end
```

Function is easy: I made a hash {key: 'link'} and have @post.content, then I downcase hash keys and @post.content and switch the words in post content with key from hash and link (so it would look like hyperlink).
Everything works fine but the problem is that it switch words in @post.content to lowercase (Hello --> hello). Is there any way to switch compare new_content and new_content_downcase, save the original word AND hyperlink on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't downcase the post's content, that's it :) You could use `gsub!` with the block to make things concise, smth. like the following:

```rb
def execute
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  keys = Keyword.pluck(:key, :link).to_h.transform_keys(&:downcase)
  
  @post.content.gsub!(/\w+/) do |word|
    # We downcase each word when we check for the links presence...
    url = keys[word.downcase]
    # ... but not when we do replacements.
    url ? "<a href='#{url}'>#{word}</a>" : word
  end

  @post.save!
end
```

Comment: Nice alternative approach! One could also use `new_content = @post.content.split.map...`, which might be a bit clearer than a `gsub!` with a regex. Either way, non-letter characters might cause problems in matches (hyphens, for example) but that level of sophistication's for later!

Comment: Thank you but with your code I've met another problem - for some reason it does not switch the words in text. When I write puts(url ? "<a href='#{url}'>#{word}</a>" : word) - I can see ' <a href='https://link.com'>WORD</a> ' - it saved word from @post.content without changes. But I do not understand - why it doesn't switched it to hyperlink in my text.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like I've made some mistake in my own code but now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So, your output is all lower case because you've applied `#downcase` to both your list of keywords and your content. And I assume you did that because you're doing a literal match between the keyword and the content string in your `gsub`.

One solution is to use a case-insensitive regex instead, :

```rb
all_keys.map { |key, link|
  @post.content.gsub!(/(#{key})/i, "<a href='#{link}'>\1</a>")
}
```

Here, I've ignored the `downcase` and just used `@post.content` directly (I assume that it's a string so the `to_s` is redundant).

Then, in the `gsub`, I replaced the `key` direct match with a regex. This uses brackets to capture the term that's found for use in the replace term, so that you retain the capitalisation of the source rather than that of the stored keyword. The `\1` in the replacement string is how that stored result from the regex gets used.

Fingers crossed that gets you working!

===Edit===

Here's an attempt at doing this properly, updating the entire method. (I'd also not escaped the `\1` above, which it needs because it's in double quotes. Sorry about that!)

```rb
def export
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  _content = @post.content
  Keyword.pluck(:key, :link).to_h.each { |_key, _link|
    _content.gsub!(/(#{_key})/i, "<a href='#{_link}'>\\1</a>")
  }
  @post.update(content: _content)
end
```

Don't add `key` after `\1`, as you mention in a comment - the `\1` should automatically be replaced with whatever was found by the regex (i.e. the value of `key` regardless of case).

Also, you shouldn't need to `downcase` your Keyword entries in any case: the time to do that is when they're created, so you only have to do it once.

Comment: Interesting decision, thank you. But there is some trouble - when I write it right how you did it - wipes out the whole @post.content for some reason. But I found one interesting thing - if we write  
all_keys.map { |key, link| @post.content.gsub!(/(#{key})/i, "<a href='#{link}'>\1#{key}</a>") }
 Note, that I've wrote a {key} at the end - it changes my words to keyword no matter was word in text upercase or lowercase. Any ideas how we can make vice versa, like saving the word from text but making it hyperlink from keyword?

Comment: Hmm. The dangers of quickly dashing off a code fragment. I've edited my answer to (hopefully) get you further. (I'd forgotten to escape the `\1` because the string was double-quoted, so it wouldn't have worked as was.)